# How do I properly use the gazebo API?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Say I want to rotate a joint at a certain velocity. So I browse through the API reference pages and reach [here](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a30b3b4fd789504c9dc265cddb276f3bf).

I can't seem to find any reference to the term 'velocity'. Is it linear velocity or angular velocity? Also what is it's unit? Where do I find information about it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12265/how-do-i-properly-use-the-gazebo-api?/) by [daltonfury42](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2373/daltonfury42/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daltonfury42](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2373/daltonfury42/) on 2016-01-05**:
Nobody can answer this simple question?

**Comment by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on 2016-01-06**:
Since ODE is the default physic engine for gazebo, you might find some answers here:

http://www.ode.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It depends on the joint type. Velocity will be linear for prismatic joints and angular for revolute joints.

Gazebo uses SI units, so linear velocity is in `m/s` and angular velocity in `rad/s`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0